# PHP, need refresh current page with additional information from the server, how?

Tags: php, refresh

I have a html/php page, which reads file NAMES on the server, collects user inputs, and returns results upon user clicking "submit" button. The returned results will be parsed and displayed in a table in the page. Certain functions are implemented in javascript, btw.

That's how the html/php usually works. Now I need another field that will allow user to specify a name, and I need "refresh" the page with additional info which will be read from file NAMES on the server. Let me call this ShowExtraName function, for the sake of wording.

Before ShowExtraName, I have html/php code like this (sorry for the format, not sure how to write html tags in the post):

```
<html>
<head>
<javascripts added here>
<table>
<div>
<form>
<continue html layout here>
<checkboxes with php reading file NAMES from server --- line XXYY>
<submit>
<php script to check user input and query server, then display returns in table. This section is blank before submit since certain input fields are not "isset".>
```

Now my question is how/where I can add the ShowExtraName. I believe it needs to be php, because I need determine not only user-specified name, but also get additional and related information from the server and display it in line XXYY.

Hope I describe it clearly. Thank you for your input!

Comment: How are you storing the names?  Database?  Text file?  A PHP session?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use JavaScript/[jQuery](http://learn.jquery.com/) and AJAX calls in order to be able to ask the server to execute some code and then to render the result back to the HTML without refreshing the page.

jQuery is a very simple and yet very powerful tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a number of ways.

Using only html and php, the easiest would probably be to use a form that uses GET with an action of the same page. Then check for get parameters in your PHP and print the extra row of data in your code.

```
<FORM action="" method="get">
  <INPUT type="text" id="name"><BR>
  <INPUT type="submit" value="Send">
</FORM>

<?php
   if (isset($_GET['name'])) {
       //do database query
       //echo more stuff
   }
?>
```

If you are doing a database query be sure to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Otherwise if you want to get fancy with a live refresh you will need to use JavaScript. [(jQuery AJAX)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: thanks for quick input/code. One Q, does this form has to be a new/different one than my old one? My old form has a "submit" button already.

Comment: I don't know what your "old" form does because you didn't post it so it's difficult to answer.

Comment: the submit button is in the old form. now add another submit-type button. ---------I'll test now. Thanks.